# JS. Вложенный селект - какова правильная логика?

Tags: javascript

Допустим нужно сделать обычный вложенный селект. Как выбор марки и модели авто.
Сначала выбираем марку, и после этого подгружается выбор моделей.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Написал простой код, но мне кажется что это все фуфло. И что это делается совсем по-другому.

```js
var car = "<select oninput='online2()'><option id='opt1'>Option 1</option><option id='opt2'>Option 2</option><option id='opt3'>Option 3</option></select>"
var bike = "<select><option id='opt4'>Option 4</option><option id='opt5'>Option 5</option><option id='opt6'>Option 6</option></select>"
var ship = "<select><option id='opt7'>Option 7</option><option id='opt8'>Option 8</option><option id='opt9'>Option 9</option></select>"
var res;
var res2;

function online() {
 if (document.getElementById('caroption').selected) {res = car;}
 if (document.getElementById('bikeoption').selected) {res = bike;}
 if (document.getElementById('shipoption').selected) {res = ship;}
 
 document.getElementById('selecthere').innerHTML = res
} 

function online2() {
 if (document.getElementById('opt1').selected) {res2 = "BMW";}
 if (document.getElementById('opt2').selected) {res2 = "Mercedes";}
 if (document.getElementById('opt3').selected) {res2 = "Ferrari";}
 document.getElementById('select2here').innerHTML = res2
}
```

```html
<select id="select" oninput="online()">
 <option value="">Выберите опцию</option>
 <option id="caroption">Car</option>
 <option id="bikeoption">Bike</option>
 <option id="shipoption">Ship</option>
</select>
<div id="selecthere">
</div>
<BR><BR>
<div id="select2here">
</div>
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых: значение селекта так не надо получать - это онанизм. Option должен иметь значение value, по которому и будет идти выбор.
Во-вторых: создайте массив, в котором будут храниться массивы с вариантами вторичного выбора.

```js
var e = document.getElementById("ddlViewBy");
var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
```

```html
<select id="ddlViewBy">
  <option value="1">test1</option>
  <option value="2" selected="selected">test2</option>
  <option value="3">test3</option>
</select>
```

Вот примерный пример того, как нужно это делать

Answer (score 1):

Может не работать от того, что вы добавляете элементы в DOM - после загрузки и создания страницы. Для заполнения второго select'a я б посоветовал использовать Vue. Он прост достаточно и можно циклом создать второй select.

Вот пример (ctrl+c/ctrl+v)
Получается более лаконично (если конечно не требуется голый js).
Я что-то упустил факт второго селекта и в голом js кроме как делать заранее 3 и скрывать ненужные идей нет...

```js
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#greed',
    data: {
        chosen1: '',
        chosen2: '',
        cars: [
            ["BMW", "Merceres", "Ferrari"],
            ["Honda", "Harley", "Suzuki"],
            ["Yacht", "Boat", "Cruiser"]
        ],
        carForSecond: []
    },
    methods: {
        fillSecond: function () {
            console.log(this.chosen1);
            this.carForSecond = this.cars[this.chosen1];
        },
        AlertResult: function () {
            //alert(this.chosen2);
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:v-bind="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v-on="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="greed">
    <select id="select" v-model="chosen1" v-on:change="fillSecond">
        <option value="">Выберите опцию</option>
        <option value="0">Car</option>
        <option value="1">Bike</option>
        <option value="2">Ship</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <select id="select2" v-model="chosen2" v-on:change="AlertResult">
        <option v-for="car in carForSecond">{{ car }}</option>
    </select>
    <br><br>
    <p>{{ chosen1 }}</p>
    <p>{{ chosen2 }}</p>
</div>

</body>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="main.js"></script>
</html>

<style>
    * { margin: 0; padding: 0;}
    select {border: 1px black solid;}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Для того, чтобы легче понимать, почему не работает, для начала, стоит отформатировать код.

```
var arr = [
  "<select id='select2' oninput='online2()'><option value='1'>Option 1</option><option value='2'>Option 2</option><option value='3'>Option 3</option></select>", 
  "<select id='select2'><option value='1'>Option 4</option><option value='2'>Option 5</option><option value='3'>Option 6</option></select>",
  "<select id='select2'><option value='1'>Option 7</option><option value='2'>Option 8</option><option value='3'>Option 9</option></select>"
];
```

Вы не назначили обработчики для второго и третьего элеметов массива.

Answer (score 0):

То есть с помощью innerHtml - это правильная логика?
Поправил код. Примерно так должно быть? Почему то не работает полностью, а только для селекта Car, хз чего так.

```js
var arr = ["<select id='select2' oninput='online2()'><option value='1'>Option 1</option><option value='2'>Option 2</option><option value='3'>Option 3</option></select>", "<select id='select2'><option value='1'>Option 4</option><option value='2'>Option 5</option><option value='3'>Option 6</option></select>","<select id='select2'><option value='1'>Option 7</option><option value='2'>Option 8</option><option value='3'>Option 9</option></select>"];
var arr2 = [["BMW", "Merceres", "Ferrari"],["Honda", "Harley", "Suzuki"],["Yacht", "Boat", "Cruiser"]];
var strUser;
var strUser2;

function online() {
 var select1 = document.getElementById('select');
 strUser = select1.options[select1.selectedIndex].value;
 document.getElementById('selecthere').innerHTML = arr[strUser - 1];
} 

function online2() {
 var select2 = document.getElementById('select2');
 strUser2 = select2.options[select2.selectedIndex].value;
 document.getElementById('select2here').innerHTML = arr2[strUser-1][strUser2-1];
}
```

```html
<select id="select" oninput="online()">
 <option value="">Выберите опцию</option>
 <option value="1">Car</option>
 <option value="2">Bike</option>
 <option value="3">Ship</option>
</select>
<div id="selecthere">
</div>
<BR><BR>
<div id="select2here">
</div>
```